# How to find some files in directory

Tags: python

OS - Windows 7

File Location - C:\Div1\Div2\NEWS.txt

I want to search this file in the system, means that any function that should return me the above path(exactly as above) for the file name given as argument

from IDLE

```
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("NEWS.txt"))
'C:\\Python33'
>>> os.path.abspath("NEWS.txt")
'C:\\Python33\\NEWS.txt'
>>> os.path.isdir('Div1')
False
```

from Command Line

```
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("NEWS.txt"))
'C:\\Users\\Username'
>>> os.path.abspath("NEWS.txt")    
'C:\\Users\\Username\\NEWS.txt'
>>> os.path.isdir('Div1')
False
```

Comment: are you trynig to search for this file in the file system?  If so what is the starting point of the search?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Div1\Div2')
path=os.path.abspath('NEWS.txt')
print path
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you explained results from different working directories. `os.path.abspath` calculates an absolute from a relative path, where your relative path is `NEWS.txt`. This is considered a file in your current working directory and is therefore 'appended' to it. In IDLE this is the directory of the Python executable, in a command line the directory from which you started the interpreter, which happens to be your home directory in a fresh command line.

What are you trying to do with `os.path.isdir`? It simply checks if the directory exists, not if you are in that directory or something similar.

If you want to search for the file `os.walk` is the function for you.